# WidgetKit run function before widget display data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widgetkit

I have a `widget` that fetch data from `API` that I want to display as text on my `widget`. How do I make that `API` call run before the `widget view load`?

Comment: You can’t. Widgets are updated on a schedule you provide, independent of when and how often a widget is viewed. Learn more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

Comment: @Adam So I can't run an API to get the current time, temperature and wind ms, and show that in a widget at any time? And make it update each hour?